# react-redux - connected component not rerendering on state change

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that I've passed through `connect` with a `mapStateToProps` argument to map one prop `this.props.mainBuffer` to a slice of my state tree from my store.  Only the component is not rendering when I update that part of the state.  (i realize that often the issue with redux is not changing the state immutably but I feel like I've done that).

My root (and only) reducer looks like:

```
function rootReducer(state = {}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case NEW_BUFFER:
            return Object.assign({}, {mainBuffer: action.samples})
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And the connect component is connected like this:

```
export default connect((state) => ({
    mainBuffer: state.mainBuffer
}))(WaveformVisualizer);
```

I have been working with react-redux for a couple weeks now and this has always worked.  Typically if I specify that a slice of the state tree `state.MainBuffer` and make sure to immutably update it in the reducer, the component will have a render triggered.  But it is no longer happening and I can't see why.

Comment: Have you tried console.log(action) in rootReducer? Check your `dispatch` method is getting called.

Comment: the reducer is definitely running the NEW_BUFFER case,  I've got redux dev tools running and I see the state change diff on each action dispatch

Comment: Cool. What about the props in `WaveformVisualizer `?

Comment: How do you update `action.samples` ? Is the value or reference changing ?

Comment: Can you post your component's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe we managed to solve this over in the Reactiflux chat channels.  The listed example code wasn't quite accurate - the real code was doing `Object.assign(state, {mainBuffer : action.samples})`, and that was mutating the existing state.  The solution was to actually pass a new empty object as the first argument, like `Object.assign({}, state, {mainBuffer : action.samples})`.  The equivalent object spread usage would be `return {...state, mainBuffer : action.samples}`.

Comment: At the time I made this post, this is the state my code was in.  But yes in the end, with the right other combinations of code, added the `{}` in did the trick.  But I have a question.  If `mapStateToProps` is looking at `state.mainBuffer` shouldn't the component still be triggered?  in other words, doesn't `Object.assign(state, {mainBuffer: action.samples}` change the `mainBuffer` property which `react-redux` is monitoring for shallow comparisons?  (assuming `action.samples` is a new object each time?

Comment: `connect` also looks to see if the root state object itself has changed. If the root object is the same reference as before, then it won't even re-run that component's `mapState` function.  Similarly, `combineReducers` will return the previous parent state object if it thinks none of the slice reducers returned something new. I talked about this immutability behavior in [The Tao of Redux, Part 1 - Implementation and Intent](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/).

Comment: at one point my NEW_BUFFER reducer was `return { mainBuffer: actions.samples }` and i did not see the component re-rendering.  is that code an immutable update?

Comment: It _might_ be. Depends on where `action.samples` came from.  For example, if that was the same array that was already in the state, then you've reused the existing array reference instead of creating a new one.

Comment: that just shows me how opaque my understanding of JS reference semantics are.  lets say `action.samples` was the same reference.  i still would think the freshly instantiated object that gets that same object as the value for `mainBuffer` would be considered a change by redux.  anyway, the array generated on each action dispatch was definitely a different object since each time the array was generated the function starts with `var newBuffer = []`

Comment: The issue is that `connect` will compare the fields in the object you return from `mapState`, like: `lastMapStateResult.mainBuffer === currentMapStateResult.mainBuffer`.  But yeah, that would seem to be producing a new array each time.  I can maybe take a look at the rest of your code later on Reactiflux.